# Создание зависимых списков select

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго дня!
У меня есть задача сделать зависимые `select`, соответственно чтоб от выбора в первом менялись значения во втором и третьем (с чем я с горем пополам справился показывая лишь нужные `option`), но также нужно чтоб от одновременного выбора в первом и втором `select` менялся список выбора в третьем (например чтоб при выборе `option` `1` и `option` `3` в третьем `select` выбирался лишь `option` `10`) и этого я сделать не смог. Прошу помочь

```js
const first = document.querySelector('#first');
const second = document.querySelector('#second');
const third = document.querySelector('#third');

const showOptions = {
  1: ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
  2: ['3', '13', '14', '15'],
  4: ['10'],
};
first.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const toShow = showOptions[this.value];
  [...second.options].forEach(n => n.hidden = +n.value && toShow && !toShow.includes(n.value));
  [...third.options].forEach(n => n.hidden = +n.value && toShow && !toShow.includes(n.value));
});
```

```html
<select id="first" size="1" name="select1">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Выберите товар</option>
  <option value="1">Шпон</option>
  <option value="2">Ламель</option>
</select>
<select id="second" size="1" name="select2">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Порода дерева</option>
  <option value="3">Дуб</option>
  <option value="4">Бук</option>
  <option value="5">Ясень</option>
  <option value="6">Береза</option>
  <option value="7">Ольха</option>
  <option value="8">Тополь</option>
  <option value="9">Кап Тополя</option>
</select>
<select id="third" size="1" name="select3">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Сорт</option>
  <option value="10">A</option>
  <option value="11">АВ</option>
  <option value="12">Ретро</option>
  <option value="13">Селект</option>
  <option value="14">Натур</option>
  <option value="15">Рустик</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А можно узнать что с чем должно зависеть?

Comment: При выборе в первом select option ‘1’ во втором select должны отображаться все option, а в третем лишь ‘10’, ‘11’, ‘12’. Затем если мы меняем выбор во втором select на option ‘4’ - ‘8’, при выбранном в первом select ‘1’, в третем select скрываются option ‘11’, ‘12’ и остается лишь ‘10’, далее при выборе в первом select option ‘2’, во втором select оставались бы только option ‘3’ а в третем option ‘13’, ‘14’, ‘15’. Я отчасти сделал, что надо, но полагаю, что тут нужно некое совмещение функций, чтоб при указании в первом и втором option нужных значений в третем скрывались не нужные option

Comment: @ПетрПриходько Данные дропдаунов именно в HTML должны быть или можно вынести их в JS, навпример как 3 массива и рисовать с помощью JS?

Comment: @EzioMercer У меня эти селекты привязанны к форме, с возможностью отправки данных на почту и я не знаю, если это делать указанным вами способом, будет ли отправка данных работать…я с грехом пополам, не без помощи реализовал свой замысел, НО, он как оказалось не работает в сафари…атрибут хидден этим браузером не воспринимается

Comment: @ПетрПриходько Я вам напишу вам свой вариант (чуть позже), ну как я это вижу, дальше уже сами решите подходит вам это или нет)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм, если, конечно, можно всё делать с помощью JS:

```js
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 'Шпон'
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 'Ламель'
}];

const woodSpecies = [{
  id: 3,
  value: 'Дуб',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1, 2])
  }
}, {
  id: 4,
  value: 'Бук',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}, {
  id: 5,
  value: 'Ясень',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}, {
  id: 6,
  value: 'Береза',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}, {
  id: 7,
  value: 'Ольха',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}, {
  id: 8,
  value: 'Тополь',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}, {
  id: 9,
  value: 'Кап Тополя',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1])
  }
}];

const sorts = [{
  id: 10,
  value: 'A',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1]),
    woodsId: new Set([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
  }
}, {
  id: 11,
  value: 'АВ',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1]),
    woodsId: new Set([3, 9])
  }
}, {
  id: 12,
  value: 'Ретро',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([1]),
    woodsId: new Set([3, 9])
  }
}, {
  id: 13,
  value: 'Селект',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([2]),
    woodsId: new Set([3])
  }
}, {
  id: 14,
  value: 'Натур',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([2]),
    woodsId: new Set([3])
  }
}, {
  id: 15,
  value: 'Рустик',
  belongsTo: {
    productsId: new Set([2]),
    woodsId: new Set([3])
  }
}];

const productsSelect = document.querySelector('#products');
const woodSpeciesSelect = document.querySelector('#woodSpecies');
const sortsSelect = document.querySelector('#sorts');

const createOption = (value, text) => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');

  option.value = value;
  option.text = text;
  
  return option;
}

const show = (el) => el.style.display = 'block';
const hide = (el) => el.style.display = 'none';

products.forEach(product => productsSelect.add(createOption(product.id, product.value)));
woodSpecies.forEach(woodSpecie => woodSpeciesSelect.add(createOption(woodSpecie.id, woodSpecie.value)));
sorts.forEach(sort => sortsSelect.add(createOption(sort.id, sort.value)));

const productsSelectOptions = [...productsSelect.options].splice(1);
const woodSpeciesSelectOptions = [...woodSpeciesSelect.options].splice(1);
const sortsSelectOptions = [...sortsSelect.options].splice(1);

const filterSelectsOptions = () => {
  const selectedProductIndex = productsSelect.selectedIndex;
  
  if (selectedProductIndex === 0) {
    woodSpeciesSelectOptions.forEach(option => hide(option));
    sortsSelectOptions.forEach(option => hide(option));
    
    woodSpeciesSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    sortsSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    
    return;
  }
  
  woodSpeciesSelectOptions.forEach((option, index) => {
    if(woodSpecies[index].belongsTo.productsId.has(products[selectedProductIndex - 1].id)) {
      show(option);
      
      return;
    }
    
    hide(option);
  });
  
  const selectedWoodSpecieIndex = woodSpeciesSelect.selectedIndex;
  
  if (selectedWoodSpecieIndex === 0) {
    sortsSelectOptions.forEach(option => hide(option));
    
    sortsSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    
    return;
  }
  
  sortsSelectOptions.forEach((option, index) => {
    const belongsTo = sorts[index].belongsTo;
    if(
      belongsTo.productsId.has(products[selectedProductIndex - 1].id) &&
      belongsTo.woodsId.has(woodSpecies[selectedWoodSpecieIndex - 1].id)
    ) {
      show(option);
      
      return;
    }
    
    hide(option);
  });
}

filterSelectsOptions();

productsSelect.onchange = () => {
  woodSpeciesSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
  filterSelectsOptions();
};

woodSpeciesSelect.onchange = () => {
  sortsSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
  filterSelectsOptions();
};
```

```html
<select id="products" size="1" name="select1">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Выберите товар</option>
</select>
<select id="woodSpecies" size="1" name="select2">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Порода дерева</option>
</select>
<select id="sorts" size="1" name="select3">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Сорт</option>
</select>
```

Можете легко настроить зависимости между компонентами, добавляя/удаляя нужные `id` в нужные поля `belongsTo`

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь! Но в сафари по прежнему не срабатывает…

Comment: @ПетрПриходько А что именно не работает? Есть какие-то ошибки в консоли? Просто то что я использовал (new Set) могло не работать в IE, потому что он не полностью поддерживается, но сафари все методы поддерживает. Тем более почти все методы у меня нативные

Comment: в консоли сафари выдает ошибку SyntaxError : Can’t create duplicate variable: ”sorts”

Comment: Странно, у меня к сожалению нет сафари, но на этом сайте вроде всё работает как надо https://live.browserstack.com/dashboard#os=OS+X&os_version=Monterey&browser=Safari&browser_version=15.3&device_browser=safari&zoom_to_fit=true&full_screen=true&url=www.google.com&speed=1. А ещё возможно у вас стоит AdBlock, в котором тоже есть эта переменная https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1416. Прелдлагаю переименовать переменную и попробовать ещё раз. Тут советуют не использовать `const` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091136/cant-create-duplicate-variable-that-shadows-a-global-property